# How to reference to or copy any parameter on the same command line in Powershell?

Tags: windows, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, powershell, prompt

How to reference to the path parameter on same command line in Powershell?

Is there a keyboard shortcut or builtin variable that allows to copy or reference to any parameter on the same command line? Like *1st*, *2nd* or *3rd* argument etc. `$^` prints first and `$$` prints last parameter.

For example in this one liner, echo prints the first argument when using `$^`:

```
Get-FileHash -Path C:\Windows\system.ini -Algorithm MD5 ; echo $^
```

..but how to reference or copy the third argument from left, the **C:\Windows\system.ini**, and placing it in front of the echo command using builtin variables or keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: you can take a look at making a wrapper for `Get-History`. the `.CommandLine` parameter will hold the whole text of the chosen ID ... and using `.Split()` on that will let you grab the nth item.

Comment: FYI... [What’s a PowerShell One-Liner & NOT a PowerShell One-Liner?](https://mikefrobbins.com/2019/02/07/whats-a-powershell-one-liner-not-a-powershell-one-liner) and you only have 2 arguments [-Path, -Algorithm], not 3. That ini filename is a value of that -Path argument string.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you can do this on the same line.

With two lines:

```
Get-FileHash -Path C:\Windows\system.ini -Algorithm MD5
((get-history | sort-object id | select-object -last 1) -split " ")[2]
```

In a function or script you have many more options to get to the parameters.

Not sure why you would do this on an interactive command line.

Comment: The OP's code is only a "one-liner" by his use of a semicolon to seperate two statements. You could do the same with your code! :D

Comment: Here's a short forn for the last command line from console: `(ghy)[-1].commandLIne`

Comment: @KeithMiller - have you tried to use my code with a semicolon in a one-liner? It doesn't work because the history entry is not there yet.

Comment: DIdn't think about that. I question the OP code's  status as a true one-liner -- that was the thrust of that comment :).  But `(((ghy)[-1]) -Split ' ')[2]` works as the second line, no?

Comment: @KeithMiller - yes that works, but I like to avoid cryptic commands using aliases here, verbose syntax is easier to understand.

Comment: Verbose syntax for scripting, absolutely.  But when you know the commands and are working intereactively at the console, reducing the amount of typing reduces the chance of typos. Given that the OP mentioned the possibility of a keyboard shortcut, I assumed he was working interactively.